# warning when piping apt and grep

Tags: apt, 14.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, with `apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64`.

I noticed that running:

```
sudo apt search lib | grep nss
```

this warning message is returned:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.
```

and after the output of the search results, filtered by grep (which is the same result obtained with `apt-cache search lib | grep nss`)

What does it mean exactly this WARNING?

Comment: They don't recommend apt to be used in scripts.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, of course, but it is not clear yet.. moreover, use grep on output I do not see how it could affect the program.

Comment: i found spaces in the output of `sudo apt search lib | grep nss` but there is no spaces in the output of `apt-cache search lib | grep nss`

Comment: Right. There are spaces at the beginning of line only when it is reported the short Details of the package, but for many packages are not reported at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning says that scripts using `apt` *may* break at some point in the future - that *may* relate to the way the command must be called **or** to the results.

Of course it is fine to use it interactively within a pipe, but usually scripts are intended to work for a long time - that's what is not advisable to do **now**.