# Can't install Samba

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, samba, webmin

After recieving help in question:
[Unable to Fully Uninstall and Reinstall Samba - Unique errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878373/unable-to-fully-uninstall-and-reinstall-samba-unique-errors), and having supposedly the same problem with another server, I am unable to reinstall samba.

Here are the errors I'm getting.

**This is from the attempted installation.**

```
:/media/dnsadmin$ sudo apt-get install libcups2 samba samba-common cups
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cups is already the newest version (2.1.3-4).
cups set to manually installed.
libcups2 is already the newest version (2.1.3-4).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-59 linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-samba samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules
Suggested packages:
  bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools smbldap-tools winbind heimdal-clients
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-samba samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules
  samba-vfs-modules
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,129 kB/3,081 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 python-samba i386 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [993 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 samba-common all 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [84.1 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 samba-common-bin i386 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [543 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 samba-dsdb-modules i386 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [237 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 samba-vfs-modules i386 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [271 kB]
Fetched 2,129 kB in 0s (7,745 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-samba.
(Reading database ... 243235 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking python-samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package samba-common.
Preparing to unpack .../samba-common_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking samba-common (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package samba-common-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../samba-common-bin_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking samba-common-bin (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package samba.
Preparing to unpack .../samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package samba-dsdb-modules.
Preparing to unpack .../samba-dsdb-modules_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking samba-dsdb-modules (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package samba-vfs-modules.
Preparing to unpack .../samba-vfs-modules_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking samba-vfs-modules (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up python-samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up samba-common (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up samba-dsdb-modules (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Setting up samba-vfs-modules (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**This is from trying to install another way.**

```
:/media/dnsadmin$ dpkg --configure samba
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
dnsadmin@tre-linfs3:/media/dnsadmin$ sudo dpkg --configure samba
Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
```

**This is from trying the commands listed in the error.**

```
:/media/dnsadmin$ systemctl status smbd.service
● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-03-10 11:08:42 EST; 1min 14
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3779 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 10 11:08:40 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 smbd[3779]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 smbd[3779]:    ...fail!
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, cod
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
lines 1-13/13 (END)
● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-03-10 11:08:42 EST; 1min 14s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3779 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 10 11:08:40 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 smbd[3779]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 smbd[3779]:    ...fail!
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Another command suggested from the installation error.**

```
:/media/dnsadmin$ journalctl -xe
Mar 10 11:08:40 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
-- Subject: Unit smbd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit smbd.service has begun starting up.
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 smbd[3779]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 smbd[3779]:    ...fail!
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
-- Subject: Unit smbd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit smbd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 10 11:08:42 tre-linfs3 systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 10 11:08:43 tre-linfs3 sudo[3708]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 10 11:09:02 tre-linfs3 CRON[3800]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 10 11:09:02 tre-linfs3 CRON[3801]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionc
Mar 10 11:09:02 tre-linfs3 CRON[3800]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Thanks for any help sorting this out, Ubuntu Warriors!